# OrderBy count appearing in the wrong order in Eloquent Query Builder (Laravel 4)

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
public static function artists_most_popular() {
        $artists_most_popular = DB::table('artists')
                        ->join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                        ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(*)', 'DESC'))
                        ->groupBy('artists.id')
                        ->take(50)
                        ->get();

        return $artists_most_popular;
    }
```

As you can see from the query, I would like the data to appear in descending order by count of the times the artist_id appears in the fanartists table.  However, when I use "foreach" and output this data, it appears in ascending order.  Any ideas for why this is happening?  I used the following query in SQL Pro, and it works as it should:

```
select *, COUNT(*)
from artists
join fanartists on artists.id = fanartists.artist_id 
group by artists.id
order by (COUNT(*)) desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed the query little bit. Hopefully this will work.

```
$artists_most_popular = DB::table('artists')
                        ->join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                        ->select(DB::raw('artists.*, fanartists.*, COUNT(*) AS total_artists'))
                        ->orderBy('total_artists', 'DESC'))
                        ->groupBy('artists.id')
                        ->take(50)
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want your Artists collection to be returned (this pretends your Artists Model is called Artists), and to further enhance Anam's response, you could do something like:

```
$artists_most_popular = Artists::join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                    ->select(DB::raw('artists.*, fanartists.*, COUNT(*) AS total_artists'))
                    ->orderBy('total_artists', 'DESC'))
                    ->groupBy('artists.id')
                    ->take(50)
                    ->get();
```